# Getting error when run the build.xml in Cakuban project

Tags: xml, unit-testing, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

We planed to use Cakupan ([Link](https://code.google.com/p/cakupan/)) as the XSLT unit test coverage tool. We have downloaded the sample project and ran the build.xml. At that time we are betting the bellow error.

**C:\Cakupan\build.xml:143: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream**

I set all the relatd lib in the class path. Bellow build.xml content can make sure that.

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
<path id="classpath.xslt">
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/commons-lang-2.1.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/xstream-1.4.4.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/saxon9.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/xalan-2.6.0.jar" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/${ant.test.lib}" />
   <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.10.jar" />
</path>
```

I have put all the jars in the lib folder. Please find bellow screen shot

Note: XStream.class is availabe in xstream-1.4.4.jar

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed this issue with the help of Patrick (One of the outhor of Cakupan - patrick.oosterveld@gmail.com).

We have to add the xstream jar and xpp3-1.1.4c jar file in the global entries of the ant runtime classpath definition of eclipse.